# Assigning Outlook 2010 Categories from Dynamic-Array using VBA

Tags: vba, function, outlook, categories, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to build a sender domain Array from a txt file to assign categories to email in the Inbox of specific Mailboxes as it arrives. The txt File would be as an example, but each P1, P2... file will have close to 500 domains per file.

```
@Symantec.com
@Microsoft.com
@McAfee.com
@TigerDirect.com
```

So far I managed to fix all the errors (Subscript Out of range, Type mismatch... etc) that I was getting with it and it runs without errors. Still, the script is not assigning categories and with the limited view of the Outlook 2010 VBA editor I have no way of inspecting what's inside variables. After it works for 1 mailbox I will make multiple Mailbox#_ItemAdd Subs for each Mailbox on the Outlook Left Pane (About 24), hence the function calls.

I have this whole thing in "ThisOutlookSession" (Copied Directly from the VBA Editor Minus the generic Mailbox names for security).

```
'Our inboxes are named here
'Variables for Display Name of the Mailbox goes here
Private WithEvents Mailbox1 As Outlook.Items
Option Explicit
Dim P1() As String
Dim P2() As String
Dim P3() As String
Dim P4() As String
Dim P5() As String

Function GetP1()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Open "C:\Priority\P1.txt" For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file.
    ReDim Preserve P1(i) ' Redim the array for the new element
    Line Input #1, P1(i) ' read next line from file and add text to the array
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Function

Function GetP2()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Open "C:\Priority\P2.txt" For Input As #1 ' Open file for input.
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file.
    ReDim Preserve P2(i) ' Redim the array for the new element
    Line Input #1, P2(i) ' read next line from file and add text to the array
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Function

Function GetP3()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Open "C:\Priority\P3.txt" For Input As #1 ' Open file for input.
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file.
    ReDim Preserve P3(i) ' Redim the array for the new element
    Line Input #1, P3(i) ' read next line from file and add text to the array
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Function

Function GetP4()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Open "C:\Priority\P4.txt" For Input As #1 ' Open file for input.
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file.
    ReDim Preserve P4(i) ' Redim the array for the new element
    Line Input #1, P4(i) ' read next line from file and add text to the array
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Function

Function GetP5()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Open "C:\Priority\P5.txt" For Input As #1 ' Open file for input.
    Do While Not EOF(1) ' Loop until end of file.
    ReDim Preserve P5(i) ' Redim the array for the new element
    Line Input #1, P5(i) ' read next line from file and add text to the array
        i = i + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Function


Function Categorize(strheader, Item)
    'categorizes mail items P1 if a Priority 1 domain is found in the internet header
    'retains any existing categories (Create one for each Categories)
    For i = LBound(P1) To UBound(P1)
    If LCase(strheader.Contains(P1)) Then
      With Msg
        Item.Categories = Item.Categories & "," & "0 Pri 1"
        Item.Save
      End With
      Exit For
    End If
    Next i

    'categorizes mail items P2 if a Priority 2 domain is found in the internet header
    'retains any existing categories (Create one for each Categories)
    For i = LBound(P2) To UBound(P2)
    If LCase(strheader.Contains(P2)) Then
      With Msg
        Item.Categories = Item.Categories & "," & "0 Pri 2"
        Item.Save
      End With
      Exit For
    End If
    Next i

    'categorizes mail items P3 if a Priority 3 domain is found in the internet header
    'retains any existing categories (Create one for each Categories)
    For i = LBound(P3) To UBound(P3)
    If LCase(strheader.Contains(P3)) Then
      With Msg
        Item.Categories = Item.Categories & "," & "0 Pri 3"
        Item.Save
      End With
      Exit For
    End If
    Next i

    'categorizes mail items P4 if a Priority 4 domain is found in the internet header
    'retains any existing categories (Create one for each Categories)
    For i = LBound(P4) To UBound(P4)
    If LCase(strheader.Contains(P4)) Then
      With Msg
        Item.Categories = Item.Categories & "," & "0 Pri 4"
        Item.Save
      End With
      Exit For
    End If
    Next i

    'categorizes mail items P5 if a Priority 5 domain is found in the internet header
    'retains any existing categories (Create one for each Categories)
    For i = LBound(P5) To UBound(P5)
    If LCase(strheader.Contains(P5)) Then
      With Msg
        Item.Categories = Item.Categories & "," & "0 Pri 5"
        Item.Save
      End With
      Exit For
    End If
    Next i

End Function



'Set our inboxes to actual folder paths on startup. Works on any mailbox visible on the left pane in Outlook.
'Display Name of the Mailbox goes here with Variable
Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")


    Set Mailbox1 = objNS.Folders("Mailbox1 Display name").Folders("Inbox").Items
    Call GetP1
    Call GetP2
    Call GetP3
    Call GetP4
    Call GetP5


End Sub


'Grab the Internet headers of a mailitem as a string
Function GetInetHeaders(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
    ' Purpose: Returns the internet headers of a message.'
    ' Written: 4/28/2009'
    ' Author:  BlueDevilFan'
    ' http://techniclee.wordpress.com/
    ' Outlook: 2007'
    Const PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"
    Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor
    GetInetHeaders = olkPA.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS)
    Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function

' use the name delared in Private WithEvents
Private Sub smbea1_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

If Item.Class = olMail Then
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strheader As String


    Set Msg = Item
    Set objNS = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'VERY IMPORTANT

    strheader = GetInetHeaders(Msg)

    Call Categorize(strheader)


ExitProc:
    'Clear Variables
    Set Msg = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set olkAtt = Nothing

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Msg and Item, there is no Contains, ...

```
Function Categorize(strheader, Item)
    Dim i As Long
    'categorizes mail items P1 if a Priority 1 domain is found in the internet header
    'retains any existing categories (Create one for each Categories)
    For i = LBound(P1) To UBound(P1)

        'If LCase(strheader.Contains(P1)) Then
        If InStr(LCase(strheader), LCase(P1(i))) Then
            'With Msg
                'Item.Categories = Item.Categories & "," & "0 Pri 1"
                'Item.Save
            'End With
            With Item
                .Categories = .Categories & "," & "0 Pri 1"
                .Save
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function


' use the name delared in Private WithEvents
'Private Sub smbea1_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Private Sub Mailbox1_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace

    'Dim Msg As Outlook.mailItem

    Dim strheader As String

    If Item.Class = olMail Then

        'Set Msg = Item
        Set objNS = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        'strheader = GetInetHeaders(Msg)
        strheader = GetInetHeaders(Item)

        'Call Categorize(strheader)
        Call Categorize(strheader, Item)

    End If

ExitProc:
    'Clear Variables
    Set Msg = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    'Set olkAtt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This did the trick to get the script working. Now from time to time it will give me a "Run-Time error '-2147221233 (8004010f)' The Operation Failed" at any of the "Item.Save" line within the Categorize function. It is kind of random, probably depending on where in the function it found a match and it's trying to save the categories. Added "On Error Resume Next" for it to work while I figure out why is that happening from time to time.

Comment: Now sometimes in get a runtime error at "Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor" or "Set olkPA = olkMsg.PropertyAccessor"

Comment: I believe the question was answered. You can create a new question with the current code.